# Automated shell Script for creating HDFS directories and Quota Setup

Tags: unix, hadoop, hdfs

I have one cluster setup in hortonworks having ambari 2.1 and HDP 2.3. I have to create an automated Script for creating HDFS directories and Quota Setup. Anyone is having any kind of script related to this or any kind of suggestions, kindly post here.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.
This site isn't a code generator. Show your own efforts, and the community will help you. I flagged this question for closing.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my Script :

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter UserName: "  username
echo "Welcome $username!"
read -s -p "Enter Password: " pswd
echo $pswd
hdfs dfs -mkdir /$1
hdfs dfs -mkdir /$2
hdfs dfs -mkdir /$3
hdfs dfs -chown hdfs:hdfs /$1
hdfs dfs -chown hdfs:hdfs /$2
hdfs dfs -chown hdfs:hdfs /$3
hdfs dfs -chmod 775 /$1
hdfs dfs -chmod 775 /$2
hdfs dfs -chmod 775 /$3
hdfs dfsadmin -setSpaceQuota 1024m /$1
hdfs dfsadmin -setSpaceQuota 1024m /$2
hdfs dfsadmin -setSpaceQuota 1024m /$3
```

I run it on the shell via `./create_and_set_quota.sh test1 test2 test3`

Answer (score 0):

I just did a quick read on HDFS, found some pages that may help and using a shell script should suffice.

A new directory may be added using:

```
hdfs hdfs dfs -mkdir /directory_name
```

Changing the quotas can be done in the following way:

```
hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -setSpaceQuota 1k /directory_name
```

Now, if we combine the above into a script, say "create_and_set_quota.sh" and run it on the shell via `./create_and_set_quota.sh mydirname` with the following content:

```
hdfs hdfs dfs -mkdir /$1
hdfs hdfs dfsadmin -setSpaceQuota 1024m /$1
```

The directory should be created and quota should be set. Here are some more pages with samples and matching discussions:

[Set quotas for users](http://www.cloudscoop.in/?p=748)

[Create a directory and set quota, this is the base of the above code.](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/11446/hdfs-quota-is-there-a-gui-to-control-hdfs-name-and.html)

[More hdfs commands](http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/using-commandline-manage-files-hdfs/#create-a-directory-in-hdfs-upload-a-file-and-list-contents)

Comment: I have Created one script which takes the uname and password and take 3 directory as input. But my requirement is we have to create a script to generalize it, so that we can take any number of input (means any number of directory as input). Also the ownership, permissions and spaceQuota can be different for different directories. So please suggest modifications which i need to do in my script.

Comment: I would recommend to create several scripts instead of one large one: first creates the directory (with parameter `directory`, second creates the quotas per directory (with parameters `directory`, `uname`, `quota`). Then use these two in your main script along with a structured data source i.e. JSON file or string. I wouldn't recommend to create scripts with too many parameters, that makes both development and debugging slow.

Comment: I have created the script...now i want something like...whenever i will run that script it should login as super user which is hdfs in my case and then execute my script. can you please suggest how can i implement this functionality.

Comment: You can use [crontab](http://kvz.io/blog/2007/07/29/schedule-tasks-on-linux-using-crontab/) to run your script periodically. Here's a [good example](http://askubuntu.com/questions/117978/script-doesnt-run-via-crontab-but-works-fine-standalone) how to set up a bash script using cron.